# How does this awk command work?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Consider the file `test.txt`:

```
pfg025G
pfg025T
pfg034T
pfg039G
```

Now consider the following awk command and its output:

```
awk '(NR>1) {print "s/"p"/"$1"/g"}{p=$1}' test.txt

s/pfg025G/pfg025T/g
s/pfg025T/pfg034T/g
s/pfg034T/pfg039G/g
```

`NR>1` is true for lines greater than one, this is valid for the `"$1"` term but not for `"p"` which takes the value of the first line. Why is that? Does `NR>1` evaluate just the first block `{}` and not the second `{p=$1}`? Why does the first `"$1"` have double quotes `""` while second `$1` does not?

Comment: someone is apparently using an awk script to generate a sed script - that's not necessary since awk can do the substitutions directly itself and generally a bad idea as it's hard to do robustly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you (splited) awk command looks like

```
awk '(NR>1) {print "s/"p"/"$1"/g"}
            {p=$1}'
```

which means

- do `{print "s/"p"/"$1"/g"}` when `NR>1`
- do `{p=$1}` always
- `"s/"p"/"$1"/g"` quote splits (1): `"s/" + p + "/" + $1 + "/g"` , neither `p` nor `$1` are quoted
- (1) `+` for concatenation, note that awk use space (no space) as implicit concatenation operator

on first line, only `{p=$1}` is executed.

on second line `{print "s/"p"/"$1"/g"}` is executed first, and value of `p` is initialized from first line.

on last line, `p` end up with `pfg039G` that is discarded.

---

Use a semicolon in the same code block in order to create a series of commands:

```
awk '(NR>1) {print "s/"p"/"$1"/g" ; p=$1}' test.txt
s//pfg025T/g
s/pfg025T/pfg034T/g
s/pfg034T/pfg039G/g
```

Now the result is as expected using `$1` from the previous match - in the first line, `$1` is empty.

Comment: what about the use of double quotes and no quotes on "$1" $1

Comment: @alex The double quotes are not around `$1` but around `/` and `/g`. I would have written the statement as `printf "s/%s/%s/g\n", p, $1`.

Comment: ok nice I understand now, thanks.